# React hook to play audio with Web Audio API

Tags: react.js, typescript, jsx, audio

My goal was to make playing sounds in my React game easy and efficient. Using `<audio>` tags wasn't an option, because on mobile it creates huge delays between the action and the sound. I'm just starting with the Web Audio API, so please forgive me if I did something silly. It works though.

I decided to make it a React hook called `useAudio()`:

```js
import { useMemo, useCallback } from "react";

const useAudio = (paths: Map<unknown, string>) => {
    const audioContext = useMemo(
        () => new AudioContext(),
        []
    );

    const arrayBuffers = useMemo(
        () => new Map([ ...paths ].map(
            ([ key, path ]) => [
                key,
                fetch(path).then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
            ]
        )),
        [paths]
    );

    const decodedTracks = useMemo(
        () => new Map([ ...arrayBuffers ].map(
            ([ key, arrayBufferPromise ]) => [
                key,
                arrayBufferPromise.then(
                    arrayBuffer => audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer)
                )
            ]
        )),
        [arrayBuffers, audioContext]
    );

    const play = useCallback(
        async (key: unknown) => {
            if (!decodedTracks.has(key)) {
                throw new Error("Invalid track key");
            }

            const decodedTrack = await decodedTracks.get(key)!;
            const bufferSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();

            bufferSource.buffer = decodedTrack;
            bufferSource.connect(audioContext.destination);

            bufferSource.start();
        },
        [audioContext, decodedTracks]
    );

    return [ play ] as const;
};

export default useAudio;
```

And here's how you'd use it in your app:

```
const audioFiles = new Map([
    ["cat", "./audio/Meow.mp3"],
    [true, "https://pikachu.test/pikapika.wav"], // You can use any key you wish!
    [777, "./lucky.aac"],
]);

const Harmony = () => {
    const [ playAudio ] = useAudio(audioFiles);

    return (
        <nav>
            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => playAudio("cat")}
            >
                Meow!
            </button>
            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => playAudio(true)}
            >
                Pika pika
            </button>
            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => playAudio(123)}
            >
                Gonna throw an error at ya!
            </button>
        </nav>
    );
};
```

I wanted to allow using any format of a key, hence using `Map` of `unknown` keys.

The main reason I'm asking for your reviews is to understand if I'm using Web Audio API correctly and if I could further optimize it, or perhaps I over-optimized something at the cost of clarity? I tried to memoize and reuse as much as I knew was possible.